# Creating a function which copies from various lines

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying my first VBA script which includes a function which should go to a external excel file, copy multiple cells and paste it back into my main excel sheet.

My questions is then. How should i construct the below script into a function of which copies muliple cells and put them back into B11:B17 for example?

```
'## Open former report first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

'Now, copy what you want from x:
x.ActiveSheet.Range("F70:F76").Copy

'Now, paste to my repport worksheet:
Windows(myName).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

'Close x:
x.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming x is a workbook variable. By setting the transpose:= true option your results will paste into B11:G11, not B11:B17.

I'd recommend using a workbook variable for your current workbook too, rather than the windows.activate command. Something like this.

```
Dim wbActive as workbook
Dim wbFormerRpt as workbook

set wbActive = Thisworkbook

'## Open former report first:
Set wbFormerRpt  = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

'Now, copy what you want from x:
wbFormerRpt.ActiveSheet.Range("F70:F76").Copy

'Now, paste to my repport worksheet:
wbActive.Activate
wbActive.ActiveSheet.Range("B11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues', Transpose:=True

wbFormerRpt.Close
```

Hope this helps.